# MC9090 Windows CE 5.0 Connectivity Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

Env: MC9090 , Windows CE 5.0, .NET3.5 CF, Windows Mobile Center, VS 2008

I'm trying to perform On device debugging on MC9090 from the VS2008 using an USB connectivity.
My app is a web application and needs an Internet connectivity. 
Unfortunately, I get connected to the Internet only when the device is out of the cradle and once it is placed inside the cradle the Internet connectivity goes off.
In brief, you get connected to the Internet or the USB when the device is on the cradle.

Have any of you faced a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the PC OS you are using, you'll have either ActiveSync or Windows Mobile Device Center (WMDC) installed. In either case, what you need to do is find the Connection Settings dialog with that app and ensure that the drop down list labelled "My computer is connected too" says "The Internet".  Technically you should be able to leave the setting as "Automatic", but there are issues with certain device / workstation combinations.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thankyou. In addition to what you had mentioned, it is also required to enable the "Allow Automatic device Authentication". I figured this out after goign thru their manual.

Answer (score 0):

Also worth to mention, that if you have turned on Advanced Network Functionality on scanner, firewall on your PC can successfully block any attempt to connect.